# Memory leak in linklist

Tags: memory

My code doesn't work unless I uncomment the statement of `list c = (list)malloc(sizeof(Node));` in the `merge_List` function and comment the statement `List c;`, which means I dynamically allocated the memory for the pointer c.

I don't know why, can someone explain to me? I would be appreciative.
By the way the function create_Node() works perfectly fine in other code, so don't worry about this function.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    struct Node *next;
    int value;
}Node,*list;

list create_Node()
{
    list head = (list)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if(!head) exit(-1);
    list tail = head;
    int len;
    int val;
    printf("Please enter the length of the list:\n ");
    scanf("%d",&len);
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        list new = (list)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        if(!new) exit(-1);
        printf("Please enter the value of the node:\n ");
        scanf(" %d",&val);
        new->value=val;
        tail->next= new; 
        tail =new;
    }
    return head;
}

list merge_List(list a,list b)
{
    if(a==NULL||b==NULL) exit(-1);
    //list c = (list)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    list c;

    list d = c;
    while(a&&b)
   {
       if(a->value<=b->value)
       {
           c->next=a;
           c=a;
           a=a->next;
       }
       else
       {
           c->next = b;
           c=b;
           b=b->next;
       }
   }
    c->next = a?a:b;
    return d;
}

int main() {
    list  l = create_Node();
    l=l->next; //the first node is NULL
    list j = create_Node();
    j=j->next;//the first node is NULL
    list n =merge_List(l,j);
    n=n->next;//the first node is NULL
    while(n)
    {
        printf("%d\n",n->value);
        n=n->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please reformat the question so the code displays properly, and include the exact error you get from it, not your own synopsis.  Those details matter.

Comment: I know  I am working on that

Comment: list is a pointer to node and the declaration "list c;" just declares a pointer that points to nothing.  Hence "c->next=whatever" is a memory fault.